# Does Magento slow down after 5,000 SKU's are added?

Tags: magento-enterprise

Thanks for reading my question. Our company is currently in negotiations with Magento to choose our licensing contract and a solutions partner. This past week our VP of IT was traveling and meet someone who uses Magento and he said it's a great platform for anything under 5,000 SKU's. Once you get over 5,000 SKU's the site slows down considerably and the search takes a long time to return results.

Is this true? Are there issues when you have over 5,000 SKU's? What issues do you have? Is there work-arounds? Are they costly?

Thank you,
Jerry

Comment: Not directly related to the question and maybe not a consideration for you but you may be interested to look at [this](http://de.meet-magento.com/2014/07/harsh-truth-magento-enterprise/?lang=en) before you commit to EE over CE.

Answer (score 3):

The person who told them that was lying. If you use Magento EE, you should be evaluating your hosting as well with Magento. Your pre sales engineer at magento , possibly Piotr, will be recommending the server setup applicable to your catalog size. As long as you have server resources to match the complexity of your catalog, magento will perform well. Follow white papers and best practices (enable flat product / flat category etc)

I have had issues with over 100k skus and search time, but that is why EE uses SOLR for advanced searching (which is VERY fast even with 200k skus)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate you taking the time to give your input. It seems the issues are more server-side than application impairments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends strongly on your product data.
A lot of different Attributes can increase the effect on.

Also you need to choose your Server depending on the needs you have. One Server may work for 2,000 SKUs, but slows down from 5,000 on.

But: as you directly tagged the enterprise edition.
I only worked with the community version, but I know the enterprise edition includes the use of SOLR for search, which means the number of SKUs should have no effect on time for results, only increase the needed memory.

But even in the community version, you dont always use the standard solutions from a certain size on. Most of the bigger Shops use special modules with an additional search server.

And depending on the produkt data you have, your bottleneck may be on another place. There is no general Answer, but number of products is usually not the Problem.

Comment: Thank you both for your input. It seems the issues are more server-side/memory than application restrictions. Again, I thank you.